# Failed loading xdebug.so: undefined symbol: gc_globals

Tags: php, installation, xdebug

I have tried to install Xdebug extension for PHP on my computer (Linux Mint, PHP version 7.3.6).

I have followed instructions form [Xdebug wizard page](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). When I finished I had run following command in terminal:

```
php --version
```

It shows me version of my PHP but also a following warning:

> Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: gc_globals

Xdebug is not listed as enabled extension when calling phpinfo() either. Could you please help, where can be problem with my Xdebug installation?

I have installed Xdebug using following steps from the wizard page:

```
• Download xdebug-2.7.2.tgz
• Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions.
• On your Ubuntu system, install them with: apt-get install php-dev autoconf automake
• Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.7.2.tgz
• Run: cd xdebug-2.7.2
• Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize).
• 
• As part of its output it should show:
• 
• Configuring for:
• ...
• Zend Module Api No:      20180731
• Zend Extension Api No:   320180731
• If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.
• 
• Run: ./configure
• Run: make
• Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/20180731
• Edit /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini and add the line
• zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
```

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem and in my case it happened because of different versions of PHP installed. 
CLI had PHP version 7.2 and FPM had version 7.3. So during xdebug installation version from 7.2 was used on 7.3 server.

To check CLI version use `php -v` in the terminal.

To check FPM version use `phpinfo();` page or run `php-fpm7.2 -v` in terminal (which is kinda pointless because of the version in the binary name).

The solution in my case was to remove packages related to php 7.3.

But you can fix the problem in other ways like installing the correct version of xdebug or downgrading php-fpm.

Comment: Necro commenting, but for future visitors like me, this one solved it. My CLI was using 7.2 and my FPM version was 7.4. So the CLI downloaded the 7.2 version. Thanks.

Comment: Variation on a theme... in `brew`, I unlinked my current PHP version (7.3) and re-linked the specific version I needed (7.4).

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error as you. The wizard wasn't providing me with the correct version. So instead I ran

```
pecl install xdebug
```

And then after it had completed, it said

> You should add "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so" to php.ini

So I did that and running

`php -v`

the error is gone and xdebug is installed.

If you problems with the pecl command make sure you have

```
apt-get install php7.3-xml
```

If you're not sure which .ini file to append, run

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```